# What is the word for "literature lover"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word that describes someone who loves literature? Not a lover of books (bibliophile), lover of words (logophile) or someone who loves to read(bookworm) but a single word which translates exactly to "literature lover".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if a [**literarian**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/literarian) fits the bill.

Described by OED as

> An educated or lettered person; one engaged in literary pursuits.

The [National Book Foundation](http://www.nationalbook.org/literarian.html#.W2rm-yhKjIU), based in the U.S.A has

> presented its **Literarian** Award for Outstanding Service to the American Literary Community, which is given to an individual for a lifetime of achievement in expanding the audience for books and reading.

for thirteen years running.

The following excerpt about the first-ever Literarian Award appeared in an article entitled [Taking on the establishment made Ferlinghetti a shoo-in to receive first-ever literarian award](https://www.sfgate.com/entertainment/article/Taking-on-the-establishment-made-Ferlinghetti-a-2595516.php)

> Harold Augenbraum, executive director of the National Book Foundation, which sponsors the annual awards, calls Ferlinghetti "a natural choice" for the literarian award.
>
> "**A literarian is someone who loves literature** so much that he or she wants to share it with as many people as possible, so **this award is for those who dedicate their lives to love of literature**," Augenbraum said via phone.
>
> "Ferlinghetti has had an extraordinary career as a writer and he has had an extraordinary impact on American letters," he said, citing the poet's multiple roles, including bookstore owner, publisher and victor in the famous censorship suit over publication of Allen Ginsberg's poem "Howl."

The Centre for Fiction, founded in 1820 at the Mercantile Library in New York City publishes an online magazine called [**The Literarian**](http://centerforfiction.org/magazine/back-issues/)

While researching this term, I came across [10 Words Every Book Lover Should Know](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/oliver-tearle/10-words-every-book-lover-should-know_b_5297284.html), and saw the word

> ULTRACREPIDARIAN — a word which refers to someone who gives an opinion on things s/he knows nothing about. This rather useful word is first recorded in a letter of 1819 written by influential critic William Hazlitt (indeed, he applies the word ‘ultracrepidarian’ to a critic here in its inaugural use).

I hope I'm not being one in this instance!

Comment: I'd have said "literati" but apparently, that's plural!

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco apparently literatus is the singular :) While checking my answer, I came across the word ‘logopœia’, coined by Ezra Pound which he defined as ‘the dance of the intellect among words’. I thought of 'logopœiast', but it doesn't seem to be a real word. https://interestingliterature.com/2015/06/08/27-interesting-facts-about-words/

Comment: Does literarian explicitly indicate that said person loves literature or is it more about someone who's pursuing it irrespective of their feelings? I'm sorry, I've come across this word for the first time and I wanna be sure. Interesting word though, thanks!

Comment: @Matte I've added an extra reference to the answer. When the first Literarian Award was presented by The National Book Foundation, the executive director of the foundation was quoted as saying "**A literarian is someone who loves literature so much** that he or she wants to share it with as many people as possible, so **this award is for those who dedicate their lives to love of literature**"